# Sizeof unknown type object

Tags: java, templates, sizeof

I have to get size of object which type I does not know. It's a template where I want to achieve sth like this:

```
 void sth(T data)
 {
    System.out.println("Data size = ", sizeof(data));
 }
```

How I can do this in Java?

sizeof - like a C sizeof ;)

Comment: What do you mean by `sizeof`? Java does not normally have the concept of the "size of" an object or a reference.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? That is, why do you need to know the size of a java object?

Comment: I had to check amount of data send via other library. I've done it finally using serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've used this piece of code:

```
private int getSize(Object data) {
        int size = 0;
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(bout);
            stream.writeObject(data);
            stream.close();
            size = bout.size();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return size;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not an easy task. You have to use java's `Instrumentation`.

[Here](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue142.html) is an example.

Comment: It can't be. You can't write a method signature that can accept any java type and provide it as that type if you include the primitive types.